# PHP Restrict Input to Numbers only + the number only can go upto a special amount

Tags: java, php

Ok so im coding this thing and i want people to select a number from 1-100 in a `<input type='text'>` right, so i want them to only be able to select a number inside the 1-100 , so if they typed 101 or like 300 it will echo a error or if they typed letters instead of numbers it will echo a error aswell. plus i want this code to either be  in Java or PHP. whatever is fine.

if anyone can give me this code it will be great.

Comment: SO is not a place to ask for teh codez. What have you tried?

Comment: Also, you are looking for a client-side script. That would be JavaScript, not java or php.

Comment: @KevinJohnson not necessarily. OP might be writing server-side validation. user1610205 care to comment?

Comment: @MattBall, good point. You should do both though.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a text input. Use an [HTML5 number input](http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html#type-number) ([demo](http://diveintohtml5.info/examples/input-type-number-min-max-step.html)):

```
<input type="number" min="1" max="100"/>
```

Make sure to validate the user's input on the server side as well.